# Java FX - How to use a button-with-an-image, inside an "if" condition?

Tags: java, button, javafx

This is my code, some parts have been omitted (such as imports, psvm, etc.):

```
public class Proyect extends Application implements EventHandler{

    private HBox menu1() {
        Image food1 = new Image (getClass().getResourceAsStream("clipboard.png"));
        Button btnR = new Button ("R", new ImageView(food1));
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        if(event.getSource() == btnR) {

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is my IDE says I'm mistaken in the "btnR" thing inside my if statement (it's underlined in red).

Comment: `btnR` is in a different scope. If you want it to be accessible from `handle()`, you'll need to make it a class variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Button btnR` is defined within the method `menu1()`. Hence it won't be accessible within the method `handle()`. Why don't you define it within the class as a private data member?

Please use the logic as mentioned below:

```
public class Proyect extends Application implements EventHandler{

private Button btnR;

private HBox menu1() {
    Image food1 = new Image (getClass().getResourceAsStream("clipboard.png"));
    btnR = new Button ("R", new ImageView(food1));
}

@Override
public void handle(Event event) {
    if(event.getSource() == btnR) {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: @Praven Vinny Thanks a whole bunch!